# Asp.Net MVC WebGrid helper custom attributes for table rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

Is there a way to assign custom data attributes for table rows generated by the WebGrid helper in Asp.Net MVC?

What I would like to end up with is something like this:

```
<tr data-foo="foo"></tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

No, AFAIK that's not possible. The best you could do on a `tr` is to apply a style and an alternating row style. I'd recommend [MvcContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid) or [Telerik Mvc Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx) as more advanced alternatives to Microsoft's WebGrid helper.